# NPP FAW: How to hide files by file extension?

Tags: notepad++

We use Notepad++ Folder as Workspace side pane to navigate subdirectories with source code. Is there any means to hide files by file extension? For example, we wish to ignore .o files produced after build. The codebase is legacy and cannot be updated to alter build scripts. It would be desirable to have a way to configure an ignore file, or at least specify this in the NPP Preferences window. We are using Notepad++ v7.5.1 (32-bit) on Windows 7. Thanks

Thanks to @davidbuzatto for suggesting this moved here, from SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, if I am not mistaken, there is no way to directly filter by file type. That said, if you configure a normal [Workspace with a Project](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/session/#project-panels), you can add files and folders manually and remove any unwanted files as needed.

**Notes**

- You can't filter additions in bulk but you can select multiple files to add manually (or whole directories).
- Once added, files normally can only be removed on an individual basis (no bulk selections). However, a group of files can be removed en masse if they are removed as part of a folder.